# Describe a tree by junctions

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, reference-request

I have n sectors, enumerated 0 to n-1 counterclockwise. The boundaries between these sectors are infinite branches (n of them).

These branches meet at certain points (junctions). Each junction is adjacent to a subset of the sectors (at least 3 of them).

By specifying what sectors my junctions are adjacent to, I can completely recover the tree.
This seems like something known, but I would like a reference to it.

The number of trees with n branches is given by 
http://www.oeis.org/A001003
and this is quite easy to prove.

Furthermore, if I order the sectors in the description of the junctions, I can make this representation unique.

Example:
(0,1,2,3,4,5) represents the tree with only one vertex, and 6 branches connected to this junction.

Comment: Perhaps it's just me, but I'm completely unable to parse this. Could you perhaps explain what you mean by sectors, infinite branches, junctions and what is the tree? A picture, perhaps?

Comment: This is almost, but not quite, what a Prufer code does: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence

Comment: I cannot post more hyperlinks since i am a new user,

Here are 4 examples of such trees (ignore vertices with degree 2 or less)
http://www2.math.su.se/~per/bloggimages/treeCombined22.png
http://www2.math.su.se/~per/bloggimages/treeCombined12.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that taking the dual of my trees, I always get an n-gon,
where some chords, the faces in the dual are my junctions. The bijection is now trivial.